# Any chance someone could tell me what these characters mean?

Tags: traditional-characters

I'd like to apologise beforehand in case I'm breaking any rules since I'm extremely new to forums but my curiosity is killing me!! I've had this sword for years and forgot its existence until a few weeks ago. I've been told by students who study Japanese that it's traditional Chinese and I've been told by students who study Chinese that it's Japanese, so I'm also kind of at a loss as to which language this is to begin with

[image]

Comment: `I've been told by students who study Japanese that it's traditional Chinese and I've been told by students who study Chinese that it's Japanese,` In reality, students of one language can make fairly good guesses at the other. Neither of the students being able to guess means that it’s neither language. These are random knife marks, although the third character is in a good imitation of 國.

Comment: "河內國" 日语：河内国〔河內國〕／かわちのくに〔かはちのくに〕 Kawachinokuni https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%B2%B3%E5%85%A7%E5%9C%8B

Comment: @TangHo Might as well just leave it as an answer, then we can close this question down.

Comment: You didn't even bother to take a photo at a good angle.

Answer (score 1):

It was an attempt to write "[河內國](http://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%B2%B3%E5%85%A7%E5%9C%8B)"

日语：河内国〔河內國〕／かわちのくに〔かはちのくに〕

[Kawachi No Kuni](https://www.digital.archives.go.jp/DAS/pickup/view/detail/detailArchivesEn/0303000000_5/0000000288/00)

河內 - inside the river

國 - country

Answer (score 0):

It's carved by who didn't have a good carving skill. Can't recognize a character.

1st one looks a little like 河

2nd one can be 内,丙,雨?

3rd one is a little like 国,团

I have totally no idea what it is.